# Why was Joyce Evans not in Inspector Valentine's jurisdiction?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, father-brown

At the end of Father Brown episode 6, "The Bride of Christ", Inspector Valentine says he'll charge Tom Evans as an accessory, but "As for his wife, that's out of my jurisdiction."

Why would it be out of his jurisdiction? The whole case was apparently in his jurisdiction. Joyce Evans lives in the same place as Tom. I can't make any sense of this statement.

Comment: At a guess, not having seen it: he's saying she is morally guilty but not technically liable at law.